# When inserting exponents (n) above 10, this function gives the wrong values

Tags: c

Just a quick issue I have in c. In this case x is always 10, and n varies. the function works fine when n < 11, but as soon as it goes above 11 the function churns out random values which are sometimes negative too. Any tips?

```
int myPow(int x,int n)
{
    int i; /* Variable used in loop counter */
    long number = 1;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        number *= x;

    return(number);
}
```

Comment: You're probably overflowing `long`. If the value gets above 2,147,483,647, it'll yield some other wrong value.

Comment: Peter, the max value of `int` is typically 2,147,483,647.  What `int` do you expect `int myPow(10,10)` to return?

Comment: Consider using `long long` [and/or `int64_t`] instead of `int`. Or, [if you're really brave ;-)] consider `__int128` [available on _some_ compilers]. Beyond that, for arbitrary length integers, consider the GMP library: https://gmplib.org/

Comment: Thanks chux! I converted all variables including the function to a long and it worked :D

Answer (score 1):

Typically code like this is *undefined behavior* due to `int` overflow.

Yet OP is using `long` in the multiplication, so it is UB once the product exceeds `LONG_MAX`.

When `INT_MAX` and `LONG_MAX` are 2,147,483,647 (2<sup>31</sup>  - 1), codes suffers UB with `my_pow(10,10)`.

When `LONG_MAX` in 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (2<sup>63</sup>  - 1), codes suffers UB with `my_pow(10,19)` and `my_pow(10,10)` is *implementation defined behavior* converting the large `long` to `int` on the return.

Code using wider intergern types to cope with larger values, but integer math is only good for so far with an exponential function

---

Some dusty old sample code the considers all `int` values and uses [Exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) with projection against signed integer overflow.

```
#define DIV0 INTMAX_MIN

// Likely needs work ...
static bool safe_mul(intmax_t a, intmax_t b, intmax_t *product) {
  if (a > 0) {
    if (b > 0) {
      if (a > INTMAX_MAX / b)
        return true;   // a positive, b positive
    } else if (b < INTMAX_MIN / a)
      return true;     // a positive, b not positive
  } else if (b > 0) {
    if (a < INTMAX_MIN / b)
      return true;    // a not positive, b positive
  } else if (a != 0 && b < INTMAX_MAX / a)
    return true; // a not positive, b not positive
  *product = a * b;
  return false;
}

intmax_t pow_i(int base, int expo) {
  if (expo < 0) {
    if (base == 1)
      return 1;
    if (base == -1)
      return (expo % 2) ? -1 : 1;
    if (base == 0)
      return DIV0; //
    return 0; // round toward 0
  }
  intmax_t wide_base = base;
  intmax_t pow = 1;
  while (expo > 0) {
    if (expo % 2) {
      if (safe_mul(pow, wide_base, &pow))
        return 0;
    }
    if (safe_mul(wide_base, wide_base, &wide_base))
      return 0;
    expo /= 2;
  }
  return pow;
}
```